# Multivariant or Multivariate?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

When testing performance or the output of different combinations of elements against one another - is it correct to say it's a "multivariant" test? Or is it a "multivariate" test?

Comment: Have you checked the available resources? What have you found?

Comment: To make it even more complex, there is also "multivariable" analysis. See the article [Multivariate or Multivariable Regression?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3518362/) from Bertha Hidalgo, PhD, MPHcorresponding author and Melody Goodman, PhD, MS

Answer (score 1):

This is really a technical question rather than an English question, but the answer is it's 'Multivariate": "involving a number of distinct, though not usually independent, random variables"

Comment: Independence isn't relevant to whether statistics are multivariate; moreover, *independent* may be used two ways here, referring to [dependent and independent variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables) of a research design, vs [statistically independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29), ie [uncorrelated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncorrelated), random variables.

Answer (score 1):

I've only heard of "multivariate analysis" in statistics. When I try to search for "define multivariant," Bing corrects the word and says it's "Including results for define multivariate."

Answer (score 0):

In Calculus and Statistics [Multivariate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multivariate) generally means the use of several variables. [Multivariant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multivariant), from the definitions I found, is directed towards [degrees of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom). As variables tend to represent degrees of freedom, I would hazard a guess they are somewhat interchangeable. The Ngram below does show that "Multivariant" is really not used much, so I would probably stick with "multivariate".

[image]